# Permanent Join Raster ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I combined two raster datasets. Which results in a dataset with non-descriptive information. I then joined a text file to the combined raster dataset. I want to make this join permanent. I've tried exporting raster - but the new file just drops the joined attributes. I am currently using ArcGIS Pro.

Answer (score 0):

When I initially created the join, I right clicked on the raster > joins and relates > add joins. This method creates a temporary join.

For a permanent join use "Geoprocessing Tools". Under the Data Management tools > Joins and Relates > Join Field. This will ensure that the join is permanent.